# Collectors.reducing method is updating the same identity when used as downstream for Collectors.partitionBy

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, reduction

I have a class similar to the below `MyObject`.

```
public class MyObject {
    private String key; // not unique. multiple objects can have the same key.
    private boolean isPermanent;
    private double value1;
    private double value2;
    
    public MyObject merge(MyObject m){
        value1 += m.getValue1();
        value2 += m.getValue2();
        return this;
    }

    // getters, setters and constructors...
}
```

Following is the sample data:

```
List<MyObject> objs = new ArrayList<>();

objs.add(new MyObject("1", false, 100, 200));
objs.add(new MyObject("2", false, 300, 100));
objs.add(new MyObject("1", false, 200, 300));

objs.add(new MyObject("3", true, 100, 200));
objs.add(new MyObject("1", true, 500, 100));
objs.add(new MyObject("1", true, 100, 100));
```

I want to combine these objects based on `isPermanent` and `key` and did the following:

(Note that I have added `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*` to import `groupingBy`, `partitioningBy` and `reducing` in the below code)

```
objs.stream()
    .collect(partitioningBy(MyObject::isPermanent,
                            groupingBy(MyObject::getKey,
                                       reducing(new MyObject(), MyObject::merge))));
```

The returned map is of type `Map<Boolean, Map<String, MyObject>>`.
I am expecting the map returned to be as below (ignoring fields other than `value1` and `value2`)

```
{false : { 1 : { 300, 500 } } , { 2 : { 300, 100 } }, true : { 1 : { 600, 200 } } , { 3 : { 100, 200 } } }
```

But the result I am getting is like:

```
{false : { 1 : { 1300, 1000 } } , { 2 : { 1300, 1000 } }, true : { 1 : { 1300, 1000 } } , { 3 : { 1300, 1000 } } }
```

Since I am passing an object as the identity, I believe that the same object is being updated for every group. Since a lambda cannot be passed onto the `reduction` method, is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `static` merge function that returns a new instance:

```
public static MyObject merge(MyObject one,MyObject two) {
    MyObject merged = new MyObject ();
    merged.setValue1(one.getValue1()+two.getValue1());
    merged.setValue2(one.getValue2()+two.getValue2());
    return merged;
}
```

You'll have to remove your existing non-static `merge` method in order for the `static` method to be picked by the compiler in place of the method reference.

This way, `MyObject::merge` will produce a new `MyObject` instance each time.

If you don't want to remove the existing method, you can still add the `static` method if you replace the method reference with the following lambda expression:

```
(o1,o2)->MyObject.merge(o1,o2)
```

Without adding the `static` method, you can replace the `MyObject::merge` method reference with the following lambda expression:

```
(o1,o2)-> new MyObject().merge(o1).merge(o2)
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but the issue is that the `merge` function is used in multiple other places which require merging on the same object. Is there any other way to achieve this without any change in the `MyObject` class?

Comment: @GauthamM You can add the static method without removing the non-static method if you replace the method reference with a lambda expression. It would still change the MyObject class, but will not affect code that uses the existing method.

Comment: but still that would result in adding a method to the `MyObject`. Can something be done in the `stream-collect-partition` code?

Comment: @GauthamM it can, but it won't be pretty. Let me edit my answer See edit

Comment: The last one is fine.

Comment: I have updated it to make it more shorter

Comment: @GauthamM updated your update to make it even shorter :)

Comment: @GauthamM you could use your original `merge` method by replacing `reducing(new MyObject(), MyObject::merge)` with `Collector.of(MyObject::new, MyObject::merge, MyObject::merge)`. That’s what [Mutable Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) is about.

Comment: @Holger Yes that would be a better approach. A new object would be created only for each grouping. So it avoids the unwanted creation of a new object for each reduction as in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Holger's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) comment in the above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65475422/7804477), instead of using `reducing`, it would be better to use `Collector.of`.

For the given `List<MyObject> objs` in question, the below code using `reducing` would generate `7` new objects of type `MyObject`. (A new object is generated as identity and one for each reduction).

```java
groupingBy(MyObject::getKey, reducing((o1,o2)-> new MyObject().merge(o1).merge(o2)));
```

But using [mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) with `Collectors`, the number of objects created would be reduced to `4`, which is the optimal amount of objects that needs to be created for the given input in question. (2 reduced objects each for `true` and `false` partitions).

```java
Collector<MyObject, MyObject, MyObject> objCollector = Collector.of(MyObject::new,
                                                                    MyObject::merge,
                                                                    MyObject::merge);

objs.stream()
    .collect(partitioningBy(MyObject::isPermanent,
                            groupingBy(MyObject::getKey, objCollector)));
```